# Not understanding the formula to calculate the execution time of the program task

Tags: cpu, computation

"Suppose your CPU is rated at 2.5 GHz and you execute a program task on your app that requires the execution of 16 million ISA3 instructions. If each ISA3 instructions executes an average of 3.7 mc2 instructions, what is the execution time of the program task?"

I know the answer, its 0.024.

I just dont understand why thats the answer. I dont understand where the numbers ago, if you convert a number to 1000 bts or what.

Someone walk me through it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? is exactly what you asked for with a solution how to calculate https://www.cslab.pepperdine.edu/warford/cosc330/CSChap01.pdf

Comment: That is literally the textbook im using, correct.  Im just not getting it lol

Comment: I mean, i try to google better explanations for it, but theres too many keywords i can never even find that formula